# Set Full Flutter App ( Texts only ) LTR to RTL?

Tags: flutter

I have a Blog app, and i have posts inside it, I'm trying to keep my app using English language, but i need to change only texts of my posts "the title and post description" from LTR to RTL

i tried to change the

```
TextDirection: TextDirection.ltr
```

to

```
TextDirection: TextDirection.rtl
```

but it still doesn't work, btw .. i'm using "easy_localization: ^3.0.0" in my pubspec.yaml as well

Note: i'd like to keep my app ignore the Phone language to force it to keep using English only.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

wrap the title and post description Widgets in a `Directionality` widget and set its `TextDirection: TextDirection.rtl`